# Do different cultivars of a species have different growing conditions?

Tags: growth, nutrients, beetroot

I am a novice at growing plants and want to grow bulls blood beet to harvest as a micro green. I shall be doing this in a greenhouse, but I want to know **if growing different cultivars(variaties? ) of a species requries different conditions?**

I read a [post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/what-are-the-optimal-growing-conditions-for-sugar-beet) on this SE about growing conditions for Sugar beets, and was going to simply use those recommended conditions, but I would like to cover my bases so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although both sugar beet and bulls blood beet are varieties of Beta vulgaris, the point is that you're intending to grow your bulls blood variety as a microgreen - the growing method for that is nothing like growing full sized beets in the ground, so no, the post you read isn't relevant to what you want to do. You want to use the green tops rather than harvesting the bulbous root when its large enough, so the techniques are different. Link below gives information on how to grow bulls blood as a microgreen

http://www.johnnyseeds.com/p-8688-beet-bulls-blood.aspx

In terms of growing a particular variety of beet as a beet, its always best to look up whichever one it is you want to grow to check the best growing conditions, rather than using a blanket 'recipe' for one type only, although with many, its likely they require similar conditions.

UPDATED ANSWER

Another link below describing what this particular grower uses as a medium, but I would just use multi purpose potting compost for this - there's enough feed in it already for up to six weeks, and its more or less neutral ph in composition. Don't know if you can get that kind of thing where you are though. If you were growing full sized beets, you'd need a ph of between about 6-8, so more or less neutral anyway.

https://sproutpeople.org/growing-beet-micro-greens/

Comment: I do not see anything on those guides about pH or nutrients, should I assume they are not relevant factors then?

Comment: See updated answer